# How to load data into sql sink using azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sink, azure-data-factory

I am trying to load data into the Azure SQL database using azure data flow. But for some reason, I cannot connect to my sink database. I have tried everything, but no luck. I am able to connect to the SQL database when I create a dataset, but why can't I connect to the database while using the dataset as my sink.

Please find the snippet of my flow below:
[image]
[image]

But when I want to use this dataset to load the data in the data flow, it is giving me the following error. The reason I want to load the data into SQL is that I want to delete rows and CSV and other datasets won't let me do this.

[image]

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Do you open your `Allow Azure services and resources to access this server` option and add your Client IP at the firewall settings of  Azure SQL database?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I finally got it now. You are right, that was the problem. :)

Comment: Your are welcome. I post it as answer,please mark it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your `Allow Azure services and resources to access this server` option and add your Client IP at the firewall settings of Azure SQL database.

Please follow this:

[image]