# Data Factory New Linked Service connection failure ACL and firewall rule

Tags: sql, connection, firewall, acl, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to move data from a datalake stored in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 to a table in an Azure SQL database.  In Data Factory "new Linked Service" when I test the connection I get a "connection failed" error message, "Access denied...make sure ACL and firewall rule is correctly configured in the Azure Data Lake Store account.  I tried numerous times to correct using related Stack overflow comments and plethora of fragmented Azure documentation to no avail.  Am I using the correct approach and if so how do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow me:

First:

Go to ADF and new Linked service in ADF,then copy `Managed identity object ID`.
[image: storage]

Second:Go to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1,navigate to Data Explorer -> Access -> click select in the 'Select User or group' field.

Finally:paste your `Managed identity object ID` and then test your connection in ADF.
[image: access]

Comment: The steps were slightly different from above- but it works now! Many thanks.  There appears to be some kind of alert for the "Publish All" button on the toolbar- do I need to do this? Also, do I now need to create a pipeline (new linked service) in order to move the data from the datalake into the SQL database?

Comment: Yes,you need to publish the linked service so that when you create a pipeline,you can use them to connect your data lake.If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: It won't publish, I believe because I also need to add a managed identity object ID or some kind of access for the ASQL database- is that correct?  What are next steps?
In factory resources, I created pipeline1.
These listed under linked services: Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 and an Azure SQL Database
Under Edit linked service (Azure SQL Database):
Error: Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'rah57server.database.windows.net', Database: 'RAHsample'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.

Comment: Yes,you are right.You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058624/how-to-load-data-into-sql-sink-using-azure/62060246#62060246

Comment: Thanks again.  I created a COPY pipeline in ADF and successfully published all.  SQL Database and DataLake appear to be connected with ADF.  In "Factory Resources/Activities" I established the data source (text file in the datalake) and the sink (SQL table I want to hold the data).  I cant find the tutorial explains how to manually move data into the table I created- can you provide the steps?

Comment: You can ask another question.I will answer you there.It is not convenient to answer you in comment.