# Azure Data Factory- Copy data from ADLS -to Cosmos DB - getting error while creating connection for ADLS as source

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Getting below error while creating source connection for ADLS in Azure Data Factory

Access to https://example.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/ is denied. Make sure the ACL and firewall rule is correctly configured in the Azure Data Lake Store account. Service request id: `e9508d22-3de7-4924-bc16-b759ac6cb320`

Response details:

```
{
  "RemoteException":
  {
    "exception": "AccessControlException",
    "message": "Permission denied on / [e9508d22-3de7-4924-bc16-b759ac6cb320][2020-06-12T00:33:05.7388123-07:00]",
    "javaClassName": "org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException"
  }
}
```

The remote server returned an error:

> (403) Forbidden. Activity ID: 411d2e50-42b7-4b57-aa43-33a8832dbbc2.

My Azure account is a trial account. I am using the organization id to create an account.
Could you please help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your `Managed identity object ID` at your ADLS.Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237694/data-factory-new-linked-service-connection-failure-acl-and-firewall-rule/62253524#62253524).